# Missing project templates in "New Project" dialog box in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I click on **File>New>Project** in Visual studio 2013 there are not any project templates present.

However, in a solution file(obviously created in another version of visual studio) when I try  **"Add>New Project"** all the templates are present there.

I want to mention few things:-

- I have **tried all the possible switches** like /installvstemplates, /ResetUserData, /ResetSkipPkgs, /ResetAddin etc.
- Tried this:

`Open the registry editor (regedit.exe)`

`Delete the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{version}`

`Delete the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{version}_Config`

`Delete the %USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{version} directory.`

- **Re-installed visual studio several times** even after deleting the "Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0" folder

Currently I am working on Windows 8.1.
Same setup of the product works perfectly on the another system running on Windows 7 service pack 1. What can I do now fix this problem?

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted as I am having the same issue :(

Answer (score 2):

**Inside visual studio**

On the menu bar, choose Tools, Import and Export Settings.
Choose the Reset all settings option button, and then choose the Next button.
Choose the No, just reset setttings, overwriting my current settings option button, and then choose the Next button.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zbhkx167.aspx#bkmk_reverting