# Visual Studio 2013 New Project dialog broken showing blank

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have installed Visual studio 2013 with update 2 but after successful installation When I try to create a new project , I am seeing blank window

[image]

But I am able to see some template when I try to click create a new website

[image]

I have tried resetting setting or installing template from visual studio command prompt.. even tried repairing it but no success

I have tried solution mentioned in below links but no success yet.

[Missing project templates in "New Project" dialog box in Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25325640/missing-project-templates-in-new-project-dialog-box-in-visual-studio-2013)

[Visual Studio 2013 new project templates appear empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29083474/visual-studio-2013-new-project-templates-appear-empty)

Comment: may not related to your question. Install VS 2015 to workaround.

Comment: I have problem with vs2013 ,, why should I install VS2015 ?

Comment: Just a suggestion. I saw that you had tried hard to fix it. Maybe it not worth spending more time. Keep your daily work moving is more important. I such case, I may re-install OS to fix it because I know it's predictable result after a few hours.

Comment: I have the same issue with online templates in new install of vs 2105 prof.

Answer (score 0):

1. On windows machine hit Win + R (Run Command Dialog)
2. Type appwiz.cpl
3. find Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate (this may vary) then Dbl Click.

The Dialog Box Shown below appears.

[The VS Repair Dialog Box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1exc.png)

Click on repair and wait for the process to complete.

1. You may be prompted for a reboot.
2. Your New Project Dialog Box should be back as it was.